# How can I group a variable so I can calculate the median from it?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataset with three variables:

1. US states (categorical)
2. year (continuous)
3. GDP per capita (continuous)

I want to create a table with the median GDP for each decade in my dataset (1955-60, 1961-70, 1971-80, 1981-90, 1991-97) for all US states, so that I end up with two columns and five rows.

So far, I produced the following code:

```
dataset %>%
  group_by(year) %>%
  summarise(median_gdp = median(gdpcap))
```

It creates the following table:

```
  year median_gdp
   <dbl>      <dbl>
 1  1955       2.39
 2  1956       2.54
 3  1957       2.68
 4  1958       2.73
 5  1959       2.77
 6  1960       2.97
 7  1961       3.14
 8  1962       3.37
 9  1963       3.61
10  1964       3.68
```

As seen in the table, I haven't grouped the years yet into a new 'decade variable'. I can't figue out how to do it. So far, I can only showcase the median for each individual year...
Also, how would I have to adjust the median command in my code?
I hope for any help here.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You should do:

```
dataset %>%
  group_by(year = (year - 1) %/% 10) %>%
  summarise(median_gdp = median(gdpcap))
```

Comment: Thanks!
Can you explain why this specific command groups the year variable like that?
Also, I added a rename command to my code in order to change the name of 'year' to 'decade', but in the output table the values of the year variable aren't listed as 1955-60, 1961-70, 1971-80, 1981-90, 1991-97 yet, but as 195, 196, 197, 198, 199. Why is that and how can I change it?

Comment: The problem is that you have not provided any dataset. So can't really be of much help. First the grouping has nothing to do with colapsed years. You could create a grouping variable then summarize the years to get the minimum and maximum for each group then collapse them

Answer (score 0):

You can use `cut` to divide the year into decade breaks, paste `min` and `max` year together in each group to create a year entry and calculate `median` `gdpcap` for each group.

```
library(dplyr)

dataset %>%
  group_by(group = cut(year, c(1955, seq(1960, 1990, 10), 1997), 
                       include.lowest = TRUE)) %>%
  summarise(decade = paste(min(year), max(year), sep = '-'), 
            median_gdp = median(gdpcap)) -> dataset1

dataset1
```